# How can I create a csv file from this tcpdump txt file in python?

Tags: parsing, machine-learning, export-to-csv

[image: tcpdump of dns queries and responses]

Hi everyone, I would like to turn this tcpdump (only DNS queries and responses) into a CSV file to train an ML model for an IDS. I managed to train the model already, but the reason it does not work is because I created bad csv files as I have no idea how to deal with the fact that the features for a query and a response look so different. Does anyone know how I can create a proper CSV file from this data that includes all the features from both queries and responses, even though the amount of features seem to vary and their shapes too. You can see in the picture an example of how my txt file looks like. I am trying to use python and tried to use `pattern = r'(\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+) IP (\S+) > (\S+): (\d+) ([\d/]+) (.*?\d+)\s*\((\d+)\)'`, but then I realised that not all lines look like that so half of my data is lost, but I have no idea how else I can do it. Thanks in advance!